# How to install "com.unity.Mono.nuget.mono-cecil" package to Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, package, photon

I was working on starting some work with Photon engine, and ne dependancy was the unity package version of Cecil.  There is an API reference to it, but I cannot find it in the package manager or anywhere online.  Can someone help me figure this out, I have only really used unity for around 3 years and I am very new to this engine.

Edit: I am using Unity v2021.1.5, if that is relevant

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are rather referring to [com.unity.nuget.mono-cecil](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.mono-cecil@1.10/manual/index.html).

As this is a package link you (try to) can install it into your project even if it is not appearing in the Package Manager.

In the [Package Manager Window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html) simply click the [`✚`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui-actions.html) → [`Add package from git URL ...`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui-giturl.html) and enter

```
com.unity.nuget.mono-cecil
```

and then hit `Add`.

Comment: I get errors when I do that;


`[Package Manager Window] Cannot perform upm operation: Unable to add package [com.unity.nuget.mono-cecil ]:
  Package name 'com.unity.nuget.mono-cecil ' is invalid. [InvalidParameter].`

Comment: Hm works for me on `2021.2.8f1` .. and should be the same in other versions since `2018.4` afaik

Comment: Do I need git to be connected to unity or something?  I haven't been doing [good] version management, and thus haven't used git with unity.

Comment: I just tried in Unity `2021.1.5f1` and it works there for me as well. `[com.unity.nuget.mono-cecil ]` looks like there is a space at the end? Make sure there are no typos in the package url ;)

Comment: Ah, silly me!  I will give it a shot once my editor launches.  Thanks, and I'll let you know if it works.